# VBA MSSOAP.SoapClient30 error: Incorrect number of parameters supplied for SOAP request HRESULT=0x80070057

Tags: vba, soap

**update**: so I've figured I need to somehow submit a complex type at method parameter - how do I do this with VBA?

This is my first time coding VBA and I will appreciate any possible pointers at how I can fix the problem. Basically, I've written a little soap service and it works fine - I test it with SoapUI - so I guess other application should be able to consume it.

[The WSDL the service generates is here](https://gist.github.com/abolotnov/5404528). Perhaps, it is not too friendly for consuming by VBScript SOAPClient - any points in that direction will help a lot.

I'm trying to put a bit of code together that actually uses it (VBScript below) - I've built it on top of an example I found while googling. It generates the following error:

```
Incorrect number of parameters supplied for SOAP request HRESULT=0x80070057

Module Module1

    Dim WSDLFileName As String
    Dim base64attachment As String
    Dim attachment_filename As String
    Dim summary As String
    Dim SoapClient
    Dim res

    Sub Main()
        WSDLFileName = "http://localhost:7777/?wsdl"
        base64attachment = "UG9ydG1hbiBpcyBwb3J0Zm9saW8gbWFuYWdlbWVudCBzb2Z0d2FyZSB0byBoZWxwIFBNTyBrZWV"
        attachment_filename = "test_file.txt"
        summary = "test issue with summary"
        SoapClient = CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapClient30")
        SoapClient.MSSoapInit(WSDLFileName)
        res = SoapClient.CreateJiraIssueWithBase64Attachment(summary, base64attachment, attachment_filename)
        Console.Out.WriteLine(res)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Any pointers will help, I'm lost here.

I'm expecting it should create a response like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:open="open.JiraAdapter">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <open:CreateJiraIssueWithBase64Attachment>
         <open:summary>some summary</open:summary>
         <open:base64attachment>BASE64CODEDFILE</open:base64attachment>
         <open:attachment_filename>NAME of the file attached</open:attachment_filename>
      </open:CreateJiraIssueWithBase64Attachment>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service response contains complex type object.

```
<xs:element name="CreateJiraIssueWithBase64AttachmentResult" type="s0:Status" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
```

To be able to use complex types you need to use "MSSOAP.SoapSerializer30" to create request and "MSSOAP.SoapReader30" for reading response.

SOAP UI can helps you to see the correct request structure (tags, namespaces and actions).
I think it something like that

```
Connector = CreateObject("MSSOAP.HttpConnector30") 
Connector.Property("EndPointURL") = "url"
Connector.Property("UseSSL") = True
Connector.Connect
Connector.Property("SoapAction") = "CreateJiraIssueWithBase64Attachment"
Connector.BeginMessage

Serializer = CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapSerializer30")
Serializer.Init(Connector.InputStream)
Serializer.StartEnvelope
Serializer.StartBody
Serializer.StartElement("CreateJiraIssueWithBase64Attachment";"open.jiraAdapter.test")
Serializer.StartElement("summary";"open.jiraAdapter.test")
Serializer.WriteString("another test issue for JUR")
Serializer.EndElement
Serializer.StartElement("base64attachment";"open.jiraAdapter.test")
Serializer.WriteString("Y29kZTogaHR0cDovL3Bhc3RlYmluLmNvbS9EbUx3N0oycQ0KeG1sOiBodHRwOi8vcGFzdGViaW4uY29tLzE3Q2MxVjJM")
Serializer.EndElement 
Serializer.StartElement("attachment_filename";"open.jiraAdapter.test")
Serializer.WriteString("readme.txt")
Serializer.EndElement   
Serializer.EndElement   
Serializer.EndBody
Serializer.EndEnvelope    
Connector.EndMessage

Reader = CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapReader30")
Reader.Load(Connector.OutputStream)  
/// Reader.Body.xml - response
```

Hope this help you.